# MultiOutputRegressor can construct structured models?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am interested in developing structured MIMO model, i.e. the connected model has common inputs and separated input for each target.

To implement this, I found the sklearn's MultiOutputRegressor.

But It makes grouped models that have same inputs but different targets.
When we use this kind of code. (Images also shows the grouped models having same input)

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import sklearn.svm.LinearSVR
# create regression data
x, y = make_regression(n_targets=3)
# split into train and test data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
# train the model
clf = MultiOutputRegressor(sklearn.svm.LinearSVR())
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
# predictions
clf.predict(x_test)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee8JY.png)

So, What I ask is as follows:

Is it possible to grouping models with different inputs using MultiOutputRegressor?
As like below Image? (I don't want to use ANN)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUJUV.png

If you have experiences about it please help me.

Besides, I am searching LS-SVM or Sparse-GP regressor.
But its implementation is too complicated.

I want to find the way to use sklearn.